# How do Combat Imbalanced Classes in Machine Learning Dataset

Tags: deep-learning, classification, yolo

I want to classify 5 different objects with a deep learning algorithm. I am planning to use transfer learning. 
For 2 classes I have more than 2000 dataset, and it is possible to gather even more. However, for another 3 classes, I have only a total of 300 per-class.

For example, imagine that we have a binary class of “Not-Fraud” and “Fraud” class. The vast majority of the transactions will be in the “Not-Fraud” class and a very small minority will be in the “Fraud” class.

PS. this problem can be turned into a binary classification problem if I can use one of that high sized dataset as one class and the rest as another class.
I was wondering if you tell me how can one manage this unbalanced training data?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using SMOTE (Synthetic Minority Oversampling Technique) for over-sampling the minority class instances.

[link here for SMOTE](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perform some image data augmentation on only the minority class.